# How to transform set date to adjust for UTC?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, utc

I really need some expert SQL help. I am making a stored procedure and everything is fine and dandy until I display it. Everything that is stored in the database is stored in UTC, however we get the browsers GMT offset and that is how we determine a predefined time range. The problem is eI use the date to display, however because of the GMT offset the date displayed is not correct and it confuses people. I display it as a short date and here is the part where it is transformed:

```
    SELECT
        BundleEvent.BundleId,
        CAST(BundleEvent.EventDate AS DATE)
    FROM dbo.BundleEvent WITH (NOLOCK)
    JOIN dbo.BundleUser WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON BundleEvent.BundleId = BundleUser.BundleId
    WHERE BundleEvent.EventDate >= @StartTimeGmt AND BundleEvent.EventDate <= @EndTimeGmt
        AND BundleUser.UserId = CASE WHEN @UserId IS NULL THEN BundleUser.UserId ELSE @UserId END
    GROUP BY
        BundleEvent.BundleId,
        CAST(BundleEvent.EventDate AS DATE)
```

Because I group by it as a short date I lose the ability to transform it. So when people select a Today range they might get a date from today and yesterday because of their GMT offset. Has anyone had this problem before and if so what solution did you use? Because I am working with a stored procedure I am very limited. I do not know how to fix this.

Comment: If you want to adjust for time zones you will need more than just the date, otherwise there is nothing to adjust. You could possibly predetermine there time zone, send the info to your select query, adjust and then cast as DATE. Or return the full UTC and adjust programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you should try to solve this in the database. Storing utc dates is correct. You should take care of the user's time offset in the front end (it can be different for every user right?).

The front end app should specify utc dates for the 'today' request as well.